# Input.GetTouch is not working in touch screen PC standalone build

Tags: unity-game-engine, touch

I have a PC with touch screen (win 7) where I am using [RTS mobile package](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/60184) it is using [Input.GetTouch](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetTouch.html) function to get touch input but it is not working in my PC although its working fine in android build. I am using unity5.4 standalone build

Answer (score 1):

Unity touch support on Windows is only promised, it was never implemented by the Unity team. My team had built a solution for this problem long ago, but it is closed source. Last time I checked there was an alternative on the asset store (called "windows 8 touch", I think).

Be prepared to use another API, not `Input.GetTouch` as events are not injected there.

Of course if you only need simulated mouse events coming from touch, then P0IT10n's answer will be enough. Of course multitouch gestures will be impossible then.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Input.GetMouseButton(0)`. Do an or (||) with your `GetTouch`